# How to install uTorrent on Ubuntu? - Method Fail

Tags: utorrent

I followed one of the procedures suggested but this is the error that I'm getting:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/utserver’: File exists
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is uTorrent *absolutely* necessary? I highly reccommend Transmission, as it is open source, ad free, and uTorrent has recently been under controversy for bundling a botnet with one particular install.

If it is necessary, then run `sudo rm /usr/bin/utserver` and *then*

`sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver`